# R shiny histogram drilldown on click

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggvis, drilldown

In R Shiny I have generated a histogram using ggplot.I am trying to create a functionality similar to tooltip. My requirement is When i click in the non histogram area,nothing should happen but  If i click in any of the bars,a dialog box should appear giving specific details (drill down) about the selection.example : If i click the 2008 bar,that should say 2008 sales value,if i click the 2009 bar,that should say 2009 sales value etc. I have tried finding the attributes of histogram like density but not able to finalise which approach to take.

Comment: You might want to have a look at plotly

Comment: You can maybe post your current code and some data  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi thanks HubertL and Nice...Yes i hav found a suitable code on Plotly..I wil share the code once it comes to a better shape